# Windows Form Application to Play in Browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, browser

I have created a C# Windows Form Application, I want to play it in my Browser, How do I do it?

If not possible, what suggestion do you guys can give?

Thanks

Comment: Refactor the logic into loosely-coupled components that can also be used by a web application, then build an ASP.NET application for an in-browser interface to the application logic.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible.**

But for example you can make an ASP.NET application.

If you are lucky then you have to make little changes in your code.